# After doing a git pull, what is the command to see what changed in the files that got updated?

Tags: git, git-pull

After doing a git pull, what is the command to see what changed in the files that got updated? examples would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer a simple:

```
git show HEAD^
```

Comment: this i like. keep it simple.

Comment: It usually gives you the changes in the commit *before* the current tip of the branch (presumably the merge if you haven't committed anything else in the meantime), not the merge itself. This is sometimes the right result, but more often it's not.

Comment: @duckx This command gives an incomplete answer if the most recent `git pull` merged more than one commit on the current branch.

Answer (score 4):

`git pull` will by default report something like

```
Updating 9e9a656..bb743dd
```

which is valid input to `git log` or `git diff`:

```
git log -p 9e9a656..bb743dd

git diff 9e9a656..bb743dd
```

If you lost the `git pull` output, you can use `git reflog` to review your own actions:

```
bb743dd HEAD@{0}: pull origin master: Fast-forward
9e9a656 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD^
```

So in this case, `git log HEAD@{1}` will also show the contents of the pull, and if you did anything in between (such as a `commit`)...

```
1dac876 HEAD@{0}: commit: some stuff
bb743dd HEAD@{1}: pull origin master: Fast-forward
9e9a656 HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD^
```

... you can use the `..` syntax:

```
git log HEAD@{2}..HEAD@{1}  # or log -p, or diff
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `git log` to view the commit messages (and SHAs), and `git diff <SHA-commitA> HEAD`, where  is the last commit you had before `pull`-ing.

Answer (score 1):

```
git show HEAD~1
```

Will show what changed in the last commit.

Comment: That only works if the pull only updated `HEAD` by one commit.

Comment: @duckx A `git pull` can fetch any number of commits (even zero), depending on how much changed between the remote and your clone. This works for a merge commit, but not for all fast-forwards.

Answer (score 0):

[The following answer assumes that the merge was not a *fast-forward* merge, and that you didn't ask `git pull` to use its rebase mode. In case those assumptions are wrong, probably either `git log` or `git log -p` or `git diff HEAD@{1} HEAD` will show you what you want.]

There's two different things you can do: review which *commits* got merged, and review the *changes* introduced by the merge. The former is done using `git log` (as explained in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20953949/12471)); the latter is a bit more complicated.

Normally, `git show <commit>` gives you a diff of stuff introduced in the given commit, but for merge commits this produces a reduced "combined diff". The specifics are not terribly relevant here... suffice to say that you won't see a normal diff for merge commits unless you use trickery.

The easiest way to see a diff of the changes introduced by a merge (and any conflict resolution performed as part of it), as compared to the first parent, is `git diff <commit>^ <commit>` (`^` = first parent).

For maximum detail, you can look at the diffs of the individual commits that got merged. I recommend doing this in graph view, making the whole thing slightly less intangible: `git log --graph -p`

Answer (score 0):

You want to see the files that changed in the last pull. That’s

```
git diff --name-only HEAD@{1}..HEAD
```

The [`git rev-parse` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) explains.

> *<refname>*`@{`<*n*>`}`, *e.g.*, `master@{1}`
>
> A ref followed by the suffix `@` with an ordinal specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g., `{1}`, `{15}`) specifies the *n*-th prior value of that ref. For example `master@{1}` is the immediate prior value of master while `master@{5}` is the 5th prior value of master. This suffix may only be used immediately following a ref name and the ref must have an existing log (`$GIT_DIR/logs/<refname>`).

Running `git pull` moves the current branch. `HEAD` is where it is now, and `HEAD@{1}` is where it was before the pull.

To see one–character summaries of *how* the files changed, run

```
git diff --name-status HEAD@{1}..HEAD
```

The full details are available in the output of

```
    git diff HEAD@{1}..HEAD
```